# Generics function call not compiling in java 8 extending multiple interfaces

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, java-8, multiple-inheritance

Running Java 1.8
JavaSE-1.8 (jdk1.8.0_20)

This class:

```
public class SimpleQuestion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoNothing();
        DoNothing2();
        DoNothing3();
        DoNothing4();
    }    

    public interface Interface1 {
        public void go();
    }

    public interface Interface2<X> {
        public X go2();
    }

    private static <X, T extends Interface2<X> & Interface1> void DoNothing() {
        return;
    }

    private static <X, T extends Interface2 & Interface1> void DoNothing2() {
        return;
    }

    private static <X, T extends Interface2<X>> void DoNothing3() {
        return;
    }

    private static <T extends Interface2<T> & Interface1> void DoNothing4() {
        return;
    }    

}
```

gives the compile error:

**The method DoNothing() in the type SimpleQuestion is not applicable for the arguments ()**

Why that one and not DoNothing2,3, and 4?

Comment: It fails in Eclipse. Oracle compiler works for me. I cry bug!

Comment: However, it works if you explicitly provide type arguments.

Comment: Compiles fine for me in Java7; possibly a bug in the compiler/IDE you're using

Comment: Why do all the `void` methods have a `return ;` statement? Also, `DoNothing2()` method will cause a compiler error (*untested* but based on what I see since `Interface2` hasn't been *bounded*).

Comment: I don't know what you are saying, it is working for me in java8 as well as java7. There might be some problem on your softwares or may be you are doing some other mistake.

Comment: The funny thing here is that Eclipse's auto-completion does not provide any argument stub when you select `doNothing()`, and then cries at you because there is no argument.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=446223

Answer (score 4):

The error message appears to be referring to a failure of the algorithm defined in [section 18.5.1 of the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.1).

For DoNothing, the algorithm proceeds as follows (using the terminology from the above link):

- The type parameters are

  `P1 = X`

  `P2 = T extends Interface2<X> & Interface1`

  and I'll use a1 and a2 for the corresponding inference variables.
- The initial bound set is

  `B0 = {a1 <: Object, a2 <: Interface2<a1>, a2 <: Interface1}`
- There are no arguments, so no extra bounds are added at this point (B2 = B0).
- There is a dependency of a2 on a1, so we try to resolve a1 first. It has a proper upper bound of Object, so we instantiate it to this. Incorporating `a1 = Object` involves adding the bound

  `a2 <: Interface2<Object>`
- Next we resolve a2. This now has two proper upper bounds, so we instantiate a2 to their glb:

  `a2 = Interface2<Object> & Interface1`
- Every variable now has an instantiation, so resolution has succeeded.

Hence, contrary to the error message, the invocation of DoNothing ought to be applicable. This appears to be a bug in your Java compiler.